# Jquery-TableDnd + Form.submit()

Tags: jquery, tablednd

I´m using Isocra´s tableDnD jquery plugin. It works fine so far. Now I want to submit my form in the onDrop function like

```
$("#myTable").tableDnD({
  onDrop: function(table, row) {   
    var input = document.createElement('input');
     input.name ='order';
     input.value = $.tableDnD.serialize();  
     input.type= 'hidden';
     $("#myformular").append(input);    

         $("#myformular").submit()
     }
 });
```

But the form isn´t submit. Has anybody an idea what could be the problem?

The id of the form is correct.

Comment: please post the html code also...

Comment: It´s a lot. I can say that it is possible to submit my form at another position in the code for example with the onchange-function of a select-tag.

Comment: it ll be difficult to figure out with just this much info

Comment: What could be the reason that it doesn´t work? Has anybody tried to submit a form in die onDop function of the tableDnd? Perhaps it isn´t possible generally?